# Gradle JacocoReport task triggers confusing Exception

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I'm trying to generate merged Jacoco test coverage reports in a non-standard multi-project gradle setup.  In the following gradle code are 2 tasks.  the first one, *jacocoMerge*, now works (after much struggling), generating the combined.exec file in the right place.  The second task, *jacocoMergedReport* seems to be executed without error according to the log traces, but does nothing, and there's a null pointer exception in the trace shortly after its execution.

Here's the gradle fragment:

```
afterEvaluate {
  task jacocoMerge(type: JacocoMerge) {
    executionData testTasks
    destinationFile = file("$buildDir/../reports/combined.exec")
    executionData = files(executionData.findAll({ it.exists() })) 
    jacocoClasspath = cp

  }

  task jacocoMergedReport(type: org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'jacocoMerge') {
    jacocoClasspath = cp
    executionData = files("$buildDir/../reports/combined.exec") 
    sourceDirectories = files(subprojects.findAll { isActualProject(it) }.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs).filter({it.exists()})
    classDirectories = files(subprojects.findAll { isActualProject(it) }.sourceSets.main.output).filter({it.exists()})

    reports {
      html.enabled = true
      xml.enabled = true
      csv.enabled = true
    }
    executionData.each {println it}
  }
}
```

I have verified the inputs and gradle version (2.14 - running from a wrapper launched via Eclipse) with `println` statements, and it all looks good to me.

But it generates nothing besides, apparently, the null pointer Exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.OutputDirectoryPropertyAnnotationHandler$1.validate(OutputDirectoryPropertyAnnotationHandler.java:49)
```

The full stack trace and the encouraging lifecycle messages about the jacocoMergedReport task which precede the error are available [in this pastebin file](http://pastebin.com/PzA2uau8).

I looked at the [source code on github for this class](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/1ca45860f7df7502d15056a26c10ea60749266ea/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/project/taskfactory/OutputFilePropertyAnnotationHandler.java), but oddly the line number and method name seem to correspond to [an earlier version](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/6e1546f7e9bb8909d0038bcf4d6ceb1c03d1f829/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/project/taskfactory/OutputFilePropertyAnnotationHandler.java) of gradle than 2.14.

So what causes this error, and, secondarily, why is it that gradle tells me its version is 2.14 but the stack trace seems to correspond with code from an earlier version and not with what was last committed before the 2.14 build time (2016-06-14 07:16:37 UTC, according to my build log)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue, apart from my question about the gradle version.  For some reason the report destination directories were not being set with default values, so I was able to get it working by tweaking the reports as follows:

```
reports {
  html.enabled = true
  xml.enabled = true
  csv.enabled = true
}

getReports().getXml().setDestination(file("$buildDir/../reports/jacoco/merged.xml"))
getReports().getCsv().setDestination(file("$buildDir/../reports/jacoco/merged.csv"))
getReports().getHtml().setDestination(file("$buildDir/../reports/jacoco/html"))
```